# Changing the visibility of a image inside a list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have this function in the bottom, In this function I fill the listview in the MainActivity, I can fill with any text I want, but I do not know how to hide, I tried the thing in the comment part to hide it, but did not work.

I need to check a certain condition and if true hide R.id.dire_win, if false hide R.id.radiant_win

Also I need to fill R.id.team01_pic in each row of the list view with an .png/.jpg url.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    SingleContactActivity.this, matchList,
                    R.layout.list_match, new String[] { TAG_team01_name, TAG_team02_name , TAG_RESULT }, new int[] {
                            R.id.team01_name, R.id.team02_name , R.id.result});

            //ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.radiant_win);
            //imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //TextView textview =(TextView )findViewById(R.id.text);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Update: I tried to create this function as one of the answers said, but did not work .

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();  
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_match, parent, false);
        //TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radiant_win);
        //textView.setText(values[position]);
        // change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        //String s = values[position];

          imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.team_navi);
            //imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        return rowView;
      }
```

Comment: Use a custom `Adapter` and show/hide what you need in `getView()`

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use Custom adapter instead of Simple adapter. Then you have to create a custom xml with all widgets you want (imageView,TextField, etc.). In your custom adapter class, inside the getView() method, that you have previously overridden, you can specify the conditions of imageView visibility. This example should help you:

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html

Also read this (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)